# Reduce method not return the same result when process the same array

Tags: javascript, arrays

This question is come from [how-to-sum-an-array-for-each-id-and-create-new-array-in-react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334249/how-to-sum-an-array-for-each-id-and-create-new-array-in-react),OP needs to sum data by id

```
const data = [{"id": "One", "number": 100}, 
  {"id": "One", "number": 150}, 
  {"id": "One", "number": 200}, 
  {"id": "Two", "number": 50}, 
  {"id": "Two", "number": 100}, 
  {"id": "Three", "number": 10}, 
  {"id": "Three", "number": 90}]
```

In order to do it,I just use a traditional way(check with `if`) to do it with `reduce()`

```
let result2 = data.reduce((a, v) => {
  let obj = a.find(i => i.id == v.id);
  if (obj) {
      obj.number += v.number;
  } else {
      a.push(v);
  }
  return a;
}, [])

console.log(result2);
```

And I found another answer is more elegant(one-liner):

```
let result3 = data.reduce((acc, {id, number}) => ({...acc, [id]: {id, number: acc[id] ? acc[id].number + number: number}}), {});
console.log(Object.values(result3));
```

The question is that when I ran the two methods seperately,I can got the expected result([jsfiddle1](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxa9h60o/) and [jsfiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/kuzy6p9j/))

[image]

However,if I ran them together,the seconds result(from `result3`) is not as expected([jsfiddle 3](https://jsfiddle.net/gs0edu6b/))
[image]

I do not know why this happen,can anyone help me to analysis this?

Also,I want to know if there are a more elegant one-liner solution to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your method mutates the values in data - if you reverse the order of running the two methods you'll see

Comment: @JaromandaX Even if I change the running order,I still got the same result. Can you give a more detail explanation,please? Thanks

Comment: yes, your method changes the values in the original data - `obj.number += v.number` changes `data` - change your code to `a.push({...v})` and it wont

Comment: @JaromandaX I changed the order and still got the same result, jsfiddle have added

Comment: @lucumt You need to do a deep copy of the object

Comment: `I changed the order and still got the same result` - yes, the results are the same when you change the order, you are correct, it's only when you do your method first that the second method fails on all three totals - but you don't have a fiddle with the order changed

Comment: @HappyDev - a shallow copy of each item will do

Comment: @lucumt - `console.log(data)` in YOUR code after the reduce - you'll see it has changed

Comment: @JaromandaX Can you post an answer for it,plz?

Comment: @JaromandaX Wouldn't a shallow copy share the same reference as the original object?

Comment: a shallow copy of the item object ... i.e. what I said earlier - `a.push({...v})` - fixes the mutation issue that causes the problem in the first place

Comment: @JaromandaX not that it matters much but isn't that a deep copy?

Comment: @HappyDev No. If `v.arr` was an array, when you say `copy = { ...v }`, the array is the same reference. Any change made to `v.array` or to `copy.array` would show up in the other one.

Comment: @HappyDev - no, it is not [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version mutates, as has been pointed out. It mutates the objects that are in the `data` array. So if you use the `data` array *after* your `let result2 =` then the `data` array has been mutated.

If your fiddle looked like:

```js
let result3 = data.reduce(...);
console.log(result3);

let result2 = data.reduce(...);
console.log(result2);
```

then the answers will be the same values, because the data array doesn't get mutated until your `result2` code runs. But any *other* users of the `data` array, in the future, would have to deal with the mutated values.

Meanwhile, you can either do what has been recommended in the comments and shallow copy:

```js
let result2 = data.reduce((a, v) => {
  let obj = a.find(i => i.id == v.id);
  if (obj) {
      obj.number += v.number;
  } else {
      const copy = { ...v }; // <-- don't mutate the original
      a.push(copy);
  }
  return a;
}, [])
```

Another simple way of doing this (exact data set) is to rebuild the data after the fact.

```js
const dictionary = data.reduce((dict, { id, number }) => {
  const currentSum = dict[id] ?? 0;
  dict[id] = currentSum + number;
  return dict;
}, {});

const results = Object.entries(dictionary)
  .map(([id, number]) => ({ id, number }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to archive it is to utilize the `Map` data structure in js

```
const result = Array.from(
  data.reduce(
    (acc, next) => acc.set(next.id, next.number + acc.get(next.id) || 0),
    new Map(),
  ),
  ([id, number]) => ({ id, number }),
);
console.log(result)
```